# Rotate image while pulling to refresh

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

I can't find the right answer. I have got an image as a subview in my table view's refresh controll. I want to rotate it while I am pulling to refresh. The rotation angle should be dependent on refresh's controll height. I was trying to use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation and CGAffineTransformRotate bu it wasn't working at all. Do any one know a solution for that?

Comment: Define "wasn't working at all". Do you get errors, does it not rotate, does it rotate differently than you expect?

What does your code look like currently

Comment: I am trying to rotate and change frame at the same time and it deforms the image.

CGFloat pullDistance = MAX(0.0, -self.refreshControl.frame.origin.y);
 CGFloat spinnerY = pullDistance / 2.0 - spinnerHeightHalf;
 CGFloat spinnerX = self.view.center.x;
CGRect spinnerFrame = self.compass_spinner.frame;
    spinnerFrame.origin.x = spinnerX;
    spinnerFrame.origin.y = spinnerY;
CGFloat angle = (pullDistance)/M_PI*180;
self.compass_spinner.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView, vertical scrolling and Swift 5:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let topOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let angle = -topOffset * 2 * CGFloat(Double.pi / 180)
    self.myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
}
```

Don't forget to do this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self
```